# Can a sequence with one element be a descending sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is actually a question I'm asking for an algorithm I write, but I think that this is the right place for the question.

I know that the definition of a descending sequence is that for every $n$:
$$a_n > a_{n+1}$$

A single number does not apply to the definition, does it mean that a single number isn't a descending series by definition?

**Edit:** The task asks me to write a function that gets a natural number, and outputs true if the digits of the number are a descending series, or false if not. I'm trying to think of radical possible inputs.

Comment: I would say that sequence fails to be descending if there is some $n$ such that $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ Could this happen with a single term?

Comment: What definition you use depends on what definition is more useful to you.

Comment: It depends on the precise definition you use, but it appears that sequences of length one are strictly increasing and strictly decreasing at the same time. Maybe you rather don't want to call it a sequence at all? ;)

Comment: jeez, I'm confused @_o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisely: **def.** a *finite* sequence $a_1,..,a_N$ is descending, iff $\forall n\in\{1,..,N-1\}$ we have $a_n>a_{n+1}$.

Then, for $N=1$, $n$ is coming from the empty set, hence the $\forall n\in\emptyset:\dots$ becomes true.